# Error in the APPManifest

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm developing a game with Unity for windows phone and I'm having trouble in the AppManifest.XAML file, Visual Studio is generating the appmanifest with two duplicate rows of Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile and Microsoft dlls. Advertising. Mobile UI. The store is refusing my package. How do I fix this?

> PS: Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI and Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile
>   are duplicateds

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" EntryPointAssembly="MeuApp" EntryPointType="MeuApp.App" RuntimeVersion="4.7.50308.0">
  <Deployment.Parts>
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="MeuApp" Source="MeuApp.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Assembly-CSharp" Source="Assembly-CSharp.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Assembly-UnityScript" Source="Assembly-UnityScript.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Boo.Lang" Source="Boo.Lang.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="GoogleAds" Source="GoogleAds.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="UnityEngine" Source="UnityEngine.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="UnityEngineProxy" Source="UnityEngineProxy.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="WindowsHelperPlugin" Source="WindowsHelperPlugin.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Windows_Ad_Plugin" Source="Windows_Ad_Plugin.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="WinRTBridge" Source="WinRTBridge.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="WinRTLegacy" Source="WinRTLegacy.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile" Source="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps" Source="Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="BridgeInterface" Source="BridgeInterface.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="UnityEngineDelegates" Source="UnityEngineDelegates.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="UnityPlayer" Source="UnityPlayer.dll" />
  </Deployment.Parts>
</Deployment>
```

Comment: This usually means you have 2 different versions of the same library. Go to references in your project and check out for duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to define:
AssemblyPart x:Name="Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI"
as it's child of Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile. Try to remove it.

Comment: These dlls are not in my references to The Project, visual Studio is generating automatically in The appmanifest.xaml. File in The xap has The duplicate rows